# Ajax Response Error. Unexpected Input when over 250mb

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, wcf, iis

I am having a larger ajax call to recive some pictures from WCF Rest Service.
When the Response is over 250 mb, i get an error. Dont know where the Problem is. Wcf is having the max responsesize and i dont get any webservice errors and ajax response are unlimited as far as i know.

I appreciate any help!

```
 "parserror" , "unexpected end of input"
```

WCF Config

```
<webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="secureBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="21474836470" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="320" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="163840" maxBytesPerRead="40960" maxNameTableCharCount="163840"/>
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
```

Ajax Call:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'xxx',
            type: 'GET',
            timeout: '30000000',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {              
                saveData(data.data, data.key);
                localStorage.setItem("DataLoadad", "1");
            },
            error: function(jqxhr, textStatus, settings, response) {
                alert("Error");
                localStorage.setItem("DataLoadad", "0");
            }
        });
```

Comment: there should be a problem with the parsing of ur data try to receive the answer as text , display it and see if there is a missing part of your json

Comment: I tried this. Seems fine to me.

Comment: Try deserialize the reponse you got using json to see whether or not it s a serialization problem